# NextJS error on start and build Assertion `(insertion_info.second) == (true)' failed

Tags: npm, next.js, lifecycle

All of the sudden my NextJS app won't start or build, I get the following message:

```
npm[213732]: c:\ws\src\env-inl.h:1041: Assertion `(insertion_info.second) == (true)' failed.
 1: 00007FF7A493052F napi_wrap+109311
 2: 00007FF7A48D5256 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+33302
 3: 00007FF7A48D55D1 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfElementsOffset+34193
 4: 00007FF7A494E69F node::AddEnvironmentCleanupHook+127
 5: 00007FF7A48FD5A1 napi_add_env_cleanup_hook+49
 6: 00007FFF90FE5057 napi_register_module_v1+8071
 7: 00007FF7A48FD25B node_module_register+7275
 8: 00007FF7A48F9AE0 node::Buffer::New+6352
 9: 00007FF7A48FA873 node::Buffer::New+9827
10: 00007FF7A514E85F v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+321471
11: 00007FF7A514DDF4 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+318804
12: 00007FF7A514E0E7 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+319559
13: 00007FF7A514DF33 v8::internal::Builtins::builtin_handle+319123
14: 00007FF7A522A0CD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+464173
15: 00007FF7A51C29D2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40498
16: 00007FF7A51C29D2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40498
17: 00007FF7A51C29D2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40498
18: 00007FF7A51C29D2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40498
19: 00007FF7A51C29D2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40498
20: 00007FF7A51C29D2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40498
21: 00007FF7A51C29D2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40498
22: 00007FF7A526A190 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+726512
23: 00007FF7A51BE8DA v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+23866
24: 00007FF7A52A8473 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+981203
25: 00007FF7A51C29D2 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+40498
26: 00007FF7A51EF7C0 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+224288
27: 00007FF7A526BBBE v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+733214
28: 00007FF7A51E293D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+171421
29: 00007FF7A51C057C v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+31196
30: 00007FF7A509081F v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+1839
31: 00007FF7A509092B v8::internal::Execution::CallWasm+2107
32: 00007FF7A509136A v8::internal::Execution::TryCall+378
33: 00007FF7A5071B85 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::RunMicrotasks+501
34: 00007FF7A50718E0 v8::internal::MicrotaskQueue::PerformCheckpoint+32
35: 00007FF7A49541C0 node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+672
36: 00007FF7A49545BB node::CallbackScope::~CallbackScope+1691
37: 00007FF7A4954A01 node::MakeCallback+209
38: 00007FF7A491F04E napi_wrap+38430
39: 00007FF7A49796C8 uv_check_init+120
40: 00007FF7A49842E8 uv_run+664
41: 00007FF7A4890255 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NumberOfBucketsOffset+9365
42: 00007FF7A49039B7 node::Start+311
43: 00007FF7A476686C RC4_options+339820
44: 00007FF7A570619C v8::internal::compiler::RepresentationChanger::Uint32OverflowOperatorFor+153532
45: 00007FF8741626BD BaseThreadInitThunk+29
46: 00007FF8759EDFB8 RtlUserThreadStart+40
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 dev: `next dev -p 5000`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I even checked out main branch and removed all local changes (few content pages and one form that should hit API to send data) to get back to previous state that worked, but it still doesn't work. I am on Win11 machine and have Node server running normally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. Just delete the ".next" directory and run "npm run dev" that it will work again.